# How to get updated ($scope) data after changing location with $window.location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my AngularJS application I have an update form which will let the user to post an update. Posting the update works as expected and my JSON file is updated right away. When the use presses the save-update button, I want the application to return to the main page and I use `$window.location.href` for that.

The main page consists of data which is received by my data-service, but this data isn't updated when the application returns to the main page after submitting the form. If I press F5 again, it will update the data, but I would like to get the data updated immediately after the application returns to the main page.

Since `$window.location.href` will reload the page according to the [information](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) I have read, I was expecting that changing the location with $window.location would also refresh the data. But for now, this appeared not to be the case in my application.

Is there any way to get the information on the main page updated without manually refreshing the page?

**Form Controller:**

```
myDash.controller("dbNewUpdateCtrl", function($scope, $window, dbDataService){

    //Save + Cancel
    $scope.updateSave = function (item) {
        dbDataService.saveUpdate(item);
        $window.location.href = "#/dashboard";
    }

    $scope.updateCancel = function () {
        $window.location.href = "#/dashboard";
    }
});
```

**Main Page Controller**

```
myDash.controller("dbOverviewCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams, dbDataService){

    $scope.items = dbDataService.getData();

});
```

Comment: I don't know if that's the probleme but in your main controller you inject dbDataService but you use dbTestService

Comment: Edited my question, thank you for the remark. But it was not the issue indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you are using the `ngRoute` Module, then use the `$location.path()` Method. It will automaticly apply all changes to the `$scope`.

If you are not using it, then apply the changes manualy by calling the `$scope.$apply()` Method of the scope before changing the location.

Comment: Using `location.path()` inside the updateSave-function is also not updating the data on the page after returning to the main-page. This is not a solution in my case.

Comment: no, not `location.path`. the service `$location.path()` from the `ngRoute` Module (you have to add a new scripttag to use this)

Comment: I injected `$location` in my Controller function and called `$location.path("#/dashboard");` inside my save-function. But that is not the right way it seems?

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm! Removing the `#` did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you should use `$location.path()` instead of `$window.location.href`. Also redirect your page once you save data in service i.e. on `callback` of save function.

You can check by adding breakpoints in Main Page Controller what you get after page redirect. If you get correct data from service then you check whether data set to `$scope.items` or not.

If not please use `$scope.apply()` to save data if you get error related to `$digest()` then follow the below code.

```
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.items = dbTestService.getData();
},0);
```

This code will update value of `$scope.items`.

I hope this will help you.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid window location href since it kinda breaks the logic of a spa. Where is the data saved ? Probably in the dbDataService?   You should re-fetch it after you've sended your data to the database.

Comment: Can you explain how I re-fetch my data properly after submitting my data?

Comment: Data is saved by using the Angular $resource service. The data is properly updated, my service is working fine. Think it will just fuzz the question when posting that code.

Comment: But basically you return multiple functions from your dbDataService. For e.g. Function 1 will fetch the data - Function 2 will set the variable = null; and reconnects to the database to replace them.